# run initState of main screen from other screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-test

I have 3 screens main, page 1, and page 2. I navigate from page1 to page 2. and then pop from page2 to page 1, but during this, I want to run the function of the main screen when popping from page2 to page1.. is this possible